# Windows Firewall enabled on all network Windows 2012/2012 R2 Servers

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

Our CIO has enabled Windows Firewall on all our Windows Servers. We have network firewalls (WatchGuard). I don't think enabling the Windows Firewalls is a good idea as it may cause conflicts with our network firewalls. I know you can never have too much security but I have not found Windows Firewalls to be as effective as a regular network firewall. Is there a right and wrong?

Comment: `I don't think enabling the Windows Firewalls is a good idea as it may cause conflicts with our network firewalls.` - Well the two don't interact with nor depend upon each other so I don't see how there would be any conflicts.

Comment: There is no excuse for _not_ enabling host-based firewalls in this day and age, regardless of OS. Disabling host-based firewalls is essentially negligence.

Answer (score 2):

"Effective" is a rather subjective term here.

Your hardware firewall and the Windows firewall can both block unwanted traffic. The main reason you might consider the hardware firewall more effective is because it can handle more traffic before being overloaded. But there are a variety of other reasons why the Windows firewall might be desirable in some circumstances.

For instance, your hardware firewall likely can't be as granular in **who** is allowed to pass traffic on a given port. The Windows firewall can open ports, but only allow it for a select group of Users or Computers.  Some apps use varying ports for connectivity and the Windows firewall can let the app choose what ports are open rather than needing to open the whole range the app might use at the hardware firewall.

Or perhaps the political environment in your company is such that it takes days/weeks for hardware firewall changes to be approved and app/server teams need/want more control.

Perhaps your hardware firewalls are only protecting your edge network and the powers that be want better protection from internal threats or threats in the same vlan or subnet.

In any case, [Defense in Depth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defense_in_depth_(computing)) is generally considered a good thing. And enforcing the Windows firewall to be on will likely make app teams more aware of what their services need to have open and subsequently submit better firewall requests to your hardware firewall team.